# How to calculate weights of row in pandas based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe which looks like this

```
pd.DataFrame({'A': ['C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C4', 'C5'],
  ...:                    'B': [6, 1, 7, 4, 3],
  ...:                    'C': [True, True, False, False, True]})
Out[6]: 
    A  B      C
0  C1  6   True
1  C2  1   True
2  C3  7  False
3  C4  4  False
4  C5  3   True
```

For all rows where column C = True I want to calculate the weight based on column B. resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
    A  B      C   weight
0  C1  6   True   0.6
1  C2  1   True   0.1
2  C3  7  False   0.0
3  C4  4  False   0.0
4  C5  3   True   0.3
```

Logic that applies:

sum of column B where C = True = 10 (6+1+3)

so for row 0 (C1) "weight" = 6 / sum of B where C = True

how can I achieve this with 1 line of code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
df['Weight'] = df['B']*df['C']/sum(df['B']*df['C'])
df
Out[136]: 
    A  B      C  Weight
0  C1  6   True     0.6
1  C2  1   True     0.1
2  C3  7  False     0.0
3  C4  4  False     0.0
4  C5  3   True     0.3
```

Comment: `np.sum()` might be a better choice than `sum`. Or just `(df['B']*df['C']).sum()`.